# LibGDX - Getting Tile Map Layers Problem

Tags: libgdx, tilemap, layers

While following a tutorial with LibGDX, I am working with tile maps.

This is the method that I'm using:

```
tilemap.getLayers().get("Collision Layer");
```

or

```
tilemap.getLayers().get(1); //1 is the second layer, the collision layer
```

The problem is, is that when I try to get a certain layer from the tile map, it return a null pointer error like so:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mytut.game.Player.Init(Player.java:25)
>       at com.mytut.game.MyTutGame.create(MyTutGame.java:70)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

I have tried various ways of getting the layer but none of them seem to work.

Here's an image of my tile map in the Tiled map editor:

[image: Map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through my code over and over again, I found what I did wrong:

The problem was that I hadn't initialized my tile map before I was trying to get the layers of the tile map, so it gave me the exception.

All I needed to do was move the tile map initialization before I found the layers.